# Finding the two biggest circles

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Any image of a face that I input into my program, it needs to find the eyes, convert it to binary using a threshold and then circle the eyes with a colour.

For example:

[image: those eyes!]

I want to iterate through each threshold level and draw circles if there is circles to be drawn. I want my program to then display the image with the threshold value added where the 2 biggest circles were which are the pupils.

This is my code:

```
radiusDark = 1;
for i=1:256
    threshold = double(i/256);
    NewImage = im2bw(Image, threshold); %0.4
    imshow(NewImage);
    hold on;
    for j=10:30
        [center, radius] = imfindcircles(NewImage,[j 31],'ObjectPolarity','dark');

        if double(radius) > double(radiusDark)

           radiusDark = radius;

           viscircles(center, radiusDark,'EdgeColor','r');

        else
           viscircles(center, radius,'EdgeColor','b');

        end
end
```

Comment: So what issue are you running into?

Comment: If I was to use this on another picture, it doesn't circle the eyes. I think there is something wrong with the checking if the radius is greater than a previous radius. And I have no checking for the 2 biggest circles and what threshold it was on.

Comment: #1. What do you think `imfindcircles` returns? #2, what do you think the input `[j 31]` does?

Comment: As far as #2 goes, I am asking because I want to know what you think varying `j` will do.

Comment: imfindcircles gives me circles and radius which are arrays of all of the circles and arrays that it has found. Are these overwritten each time j increments? The input [j 31] limits the radius of the circle from j to 31, which should be the largest circle on my image. This will be changed later on when I add more images. j is the minimum radius, as it increases it should add less circles until there is none left. I want to capture when there is 2 left.

Comment: Ok. That explains a few things. I will post an answer in an hour or two. I just wanted to understand what you needed to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to address what I think may be some misconceptions on OP's part:

- Every time you call `[center, radius] = imfindcircles(...);`, you are overwriting the values of `center` and `radius`.
- [`imfindcircles`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) returns vectors for all of its output. `center` should probably be called `centers` instead. It is an `Nx2` array, with `N` being the number of circles found. `radius` should probably be `radii`. It has dimensions `Nx1`.
- The range parameter to `imfindcircles` (`[j 31]` in this case), makes the function loop over the possible radii as it is. There is no need to do `for j=10:30` since passing in `[10 31]` will already return all the possible circles with radius up to 31. You just need to find the two biggest ones.
- You do not need to cast to `double` in MATLAB. It is already the default type. `threshold = 1/256;` and `if radius > radiusDark` will work just fine.
- If you really define `radiusDark = 1`, the test `if radius > radiusDark` can never fail since the returned radii are all going to be at least 10. However, if more than one circle is found, you will end up with at least a warning, possibly an error because `radius` will be an array.

That should explain a few things about what is going on and hopefully indicate a possible direction for a solution. The question is phrased a little ambiguously. You are either looking for the two largest circles at each given threshold, or you are looking for the two largest circles across all possible thresholds. I will show solutions for both, starting with the former since you already have 90% of the code in place for that.

#### Finding circles independently at each threshold

This is basically what your code is doing already. Here are some modifications that will make it work a bit more correctly and efficiently:

```
for i=1:254
    threshold = i / 255;
    NewImage = im2bw(Image, threshold);
    figure;
    imshow(NewImage);
    title(sprintf('Threshold=%0.3g (i=%d)', threshold, i));
    hold on;
    [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(NewImage, [10 31], 'ObjectPolarity','dark');
    if isempty(radii)
        % No circles found
        fprintf(1, 'No circles found for i=%d (threshold=%.3g)\n', i, threshold);
        continue
    end

    if length(radii) > 2
        % More than two circles found: find the two largest ones
        [~, ind] = sortrows([radii centers]);
        ind = ind(end-1:end);
        radii = radii(ind);
        centers = centers(ind, :);
    elseif length(radii) == 1
        % Only one circle found. This is the reason we check length(radii)
        % instead of length(centers). For this case, length(centers) == 2,
        % but it is a row vector with a single xy pair.
        fprintf(1, 'Only one circle found for i=%d (threshold=%.3g)\n', i, threshold);
    end
    viscircles(centers, radii, 'EdgeColor', 'b');
end
```

This method will open up a new figure for each threshold level. It will print a message about thresholds at which there are no circles or only one circle.

[`sortrows`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) is used to sort both the radii and centers together by radius (the first column), so that we can pick the two largest radii. These will be the last ones since the sort is in ascending order. I chose to do the selection by index to show off the full power of `sortrows`. It would have been just as easy to take the last rows of the first output argument (here discarded as `~`) and split them back into `radii` and `centers`.

[`fprintf(1, ...)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) prints formatted messages to the command line. File handle 1 represents standard output (2 is standard error). The newline `\n` is necessary here because the lower level print functions do not add one automatically.

#### Finding the largest circles across all thresholds

This is a slightly more complex scenario, but actually more sensible, since I am guessing OP wants a single location for the pupils in any given image. The key here is to eliminate the problem in misconception #1 and accumulate all of the radii and centers before picking the two largest ones:

```
allCenters = [];
allRadii = [];
for i=1:254
    threshold = i / 255;
    NewImage = im2bw(Image, threshold);
    [centers, radii] = imfindcircles(NewImage, [10 31], 'ObjectPolarity','dark');
    % This step involves a couple of reallocations that are normally considered
    % "expensive" and may give a lint warning. Just turn it off. This step is
    % negligible in every way compared to running a Hough transform on the image.
    allCenters = [allCenters; centers];
    allRadii = [allRadii; radii];
end

imshow(NewImage);
hold on;
if ~isempty(allRadii)
    if length(allRadii) > 2
        sorted = sortrows([allRadii allCenters]);
        allRadii = sorted(end-1:end, 1);
        allCenters = sorted(end-1:end, 2:end);
    elseif length(allRadii) == 1
        fprintf(1, 'Only one circle in the whole image. Strange.\n');
    end
    viscircles(allCenters, allRadii, 'EdgeColor', 'b');
else
    % No circles found
    fprintf(1, 'No circles found at all. What did you do!?\n');
end
```

This version uses basically the same logic, except it is applied to the combined arrays. The display code is similarly factored out. I used the other way of applying `sortrows` in this example.